# I am unable to launch application because of DirectX problem

Tags: directx

I am currently using DirectX 12. While launching the application from Visual Studio 2017 Professional I get error:

```
as your system
does not support the necessary version of DirectX. Please contact your System Administrator
```

And I am unable to launch the application.

- DirectX version in my system is DirectX 12.
- Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1803

[image: Dxdiag in my system]

Answer (score 0):

you should check your graphic card first if it's compatible with directx 12. If compatible then you should update your graphic cards driver.

I hope this information helps you !!!

Check out this image so you get an idea of supporting graphic cards.

[image: directx 12 graphic card support]

Comment: I have AMD k8 Processor Driver and

Comment: In display adapters it's DameWare Development Mirror Driver 64-bit and NVIDIA Quadro P620